# snake game using graphics.h library

Tags: c++, bgi

As I'm a starter , I've been trying to make snake game by using arrays and graphics.h library (Well yes it's old , but I must use them to practice for my c++ class) . I'm somehow confused about how to make the snake move properly . 
When I change the snake's direction , the shape doesn't clear properly . 
I'd be thankful if you give me a solution to fix that.

[As you can see in the picture :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5vfn.jpg)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    initwindow(700,700,"snake");
    int cx=400; int cy=200;
    int x1[701][701]={0};
    int rx,ry,sx;
    char ch;

    srand(time(NULL));

    rx=rand()%(500-100+1)+100;
    ry=rand()%(500-100+1)+100;
    x1[rx][ry]=1;

    setfillstyle(1,15);
    circle(rx,ry,2);
    floodfill(rx,ry,15);

    for ( ; ; )
    {
        delay(10);

        setcolor(0);
        setfillstyle(1,0);
        circle(cx-11,cy,10);
        floodfill(cx-11,cy,0);
        x1[cx-11][cy]=0;
        cx++;

        setcolor(15);
        setfillstyle(1,15);
        circle(cx-10,cy,10);
        floodfill(cx-10,cy,15);
        x1[cx-10][cy]=2;
        for (int i=1 ; i<=10 ;i++)
        {
            setcolor(15);
            setfillstyle(1,15);
            circle(cx-i,cy,10);
            floodfill(cx-i,cy,15);
            x1[cx-i][cy]=2;
        }

        if (kbhit())
        {
            for( ; ; )
            {
                if(kbhit())
                {
                    ch=getch();
                }

            if (ch=='s')
            {
                cy++;
                sx=1;

            }
            else if (ch=='d')
            {
                cx++;
                sx=2;

            }
            else if (ch=='w')
            {
                cy--;
                sx=3;

            }
            else if (ch=='a')
            {
                cx--;
                sx=4;

            }



            if ( sx==1 )
            {
                delay(10);
                setcolor(0);
                setfillstyle(1,0);
                circle(cx,cy-11,10);
                floodfill(cx,cy-11,0);
                x1[cx][cy-11]=0;
                cy++;

                setcolor(15);
                setfillstyle(1,15);
                circle(cx,cy-10,10);
                floodfill(cx,cy-10,15);
                x1[cx][cy-10]=2;
                for (int i=1 ; i<=10 ;i++)
                {
                    setcolor(15);
                    setfillstyle(1,15);
                    circle(cx,cy-i,10);
                    floodfill(cx,cy-i,15);
                    x1[cx][cy-i]=2;
                }
            }

            else if ( sx==2 )
            {
                delay(10);
                setcolor(0);
                setfillstyle(1,0);
                circle(cx-11,cy,10);
                floodfill(cx-11,cy,0);
                x1[cx-11][cy]=0;
                cx++;

                setcolor(15);
                setfillstyle(1,15);
                circle(cx-10,cy,10);
                floodfill(cx-10,cy,15);
                x1[cx-10][cy]=2;
                for (int i=1 ; i<=10 ;i++)
                {
                    setcolor(15);
                    setfillstyle(1,15);
                    circle(cx-i,cy,10);
                    floodfill(cx-i,cy,15);
                    x1[cx-i][cy]=2;
                }
            }

            else if ( sx==3 )
            {
                delay(10);
                setcolor(0);
                setfillstyle(1,0);
                circle(cx,cy+11,10);
                floodfill(cx,cy+11,0);
                x1[cx][cy+11]=0;
                cy--;

                setcolor(15);
                setfillstyle(1,15);
                circle(cx,cy+10,10);
                floodfill(cx,cy+10,15);
                x1[cx][cy+10]=2;
                for (int i=1 ; i<=10 ;i++)
                {
                    setcolor(15);
                    setfillstyle(1,15);
                    circle(cx,cy+i,10);
                    floodfill(cx,cy+i,15);
                    x1[cx][cy+i]=2;
                }
            }

            else if ( sx==4 )
            {
                delay(10);
                setcolor(0);
                setfillstyle(1,0);
                circle(cx+11,cy,10);
                floodfill(cx+11,cy,0);
                x1[cx+11][cy]=0;
                cx--;

                setcolor(15);
                setfillstyle(1,15);
                circle(cx+10,cy,10);
                floodfill(cx+10,cy,15);
                x1[cx+10][cy]=2;
                for (int i=1 ; i<=10 ;i++)
                {
                    setcolor(15);
                    setfillstyle(1,15);
                    circle(cx+i,cy,10);
                    floodfill(cx+i,cy,15);
                    x1[cx+i][cy]=2;
                }
            }



            }
        }
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas?